# Alternative to dropbox with direct public link and explorer integration?

Tags: backup, file-sharing, dropbox

Dropbox is blocked in China!
I need some other service that offers direct link to uploaded folders, like

> http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/123456/file.jpg from dropbox.

And also could integrate with local folders on Windows machines.
I prefer free hosting and I don't need a lot of space, probably 1 GB is more than enough.
Any help appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one of your comment replies, saying that you are now using Live Mesh.

That has now been replaced by *Windows* Live Mesh, which has just been released.  You can get it as part of [Windows Live 2011](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-essentials).

The main advantage over Dropbox is that you can specify which folders to sync - they do not have to all be contained in the same folder.

Public download is possible from your Live account webpages, when you set a folder as public.

Comment: I was going to say "the service formerly known as Live Sync" as well. Details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Mesh

Comment: @Ian C: By looking at your link, I have just found out that the final release of Windows Live 2011 was released in the last few hours.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at: http://alternativeto.net/desktop/dropbox/

The main ones that I know of are SugarSync, and Box.net

https://www.sugarsync.com/

> You can use SugarSync on any modern version of Mac (including Snow Leopard) as well as any Windows operating system.

2GB free from here https://www.sugarsync.com/signup?startsub=2

Comment: SugarSync does not provide html directory link to folder corresponding to folder on local computer.
Box.net does not have a client to sync local folders to server. 
Dropbox does all of this, but blocked in China!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SkyDrive: http://answers-tips.blogspot.com/2010/06/windows-live-skydrive-explorer.html

[Windows Live Skydrive](http://windowslive.com/online/skydrive): Free 25 GB online storage means you can Store, access, and share your files online with friends or co-workers, from anywhere.

Comment: I tried LiveMesh since skydrive does not support sync to local folder.

Live Mesh almost works, it does not has direct link to files, but only for registered users who download the Live Mesh software. Beats the purpose completely!

Comment: @Slabo:  Try out the Live Sync Beta, which will become the new Live Mesh.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not free, S3 is $0.10/Gb/Month

If you only need a gig, it might be a really good solution.

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

[A nice article about it](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/using-amazon-s3-as-an-image-hosting-service.html)